# オブジェクトに対してマップ処理する関数を型付けしたい

Tags: typescript

以下のような、オブジェクトにマップ処理する関数があります。

```js
const objectMap = (obj, fun) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(fun));

objectMap({a: 2, b: 4}, ([key, val]) => [key, val * 2]) // {a: 4, b: 8}
```

この関数をtsで型付けしたいのですが上手く行かないです。

以下のように試して見たのですが、

```
type ObjectMap = <K extends keyof O1, O1 extends Record<string, V1>, O2 extends Record<K, V2>, V1, V2>(
  obj: O1,
  fun: (arg: [K, V1]) => [K, V2],
) => O2;
const objectMap: ObjectMap = (obj, fun) => {
  const a = Object.entries(obj);
  const b = a.map(fun)
  const c = Object.fromEntries(b);

  return c;
};
```

a.map(fun)の箇所で

```
型 '(arg: [K, V1]) => [K, V2]' の引数を型 '(value: [string, V1], index: number, array: [string, V1][]) => [K, V2]' のパラメーターに割り当てることはできません。 ts(2345)
```

とエラーが出てしまいました。

どのように型付けしたら良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Object.entries()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/0326534/lib/lib.es2017.object.d.ts#L38) が

```
entries<T>(o: { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>): [string, T][];
```

また、 [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/065a996345fcfafd3c744d2a724a1ae9f31f9ab0/lib/lib.es2019.object.d.ts#L28) が

```
fromEntries<T = any>(entries: Iterable<readonly [PropertyKey, T]>): { [k: string]: T };
```

と型付けされているので、逆算すると次のようになるのではないでしょうか。

```
type ObjectMap = <V, R>(
  obj: { [s: string]: V } | ArrayLike<V>,
  fun: (arg: [string, V]) => [PropertyKey, R]
) => { [s: string]: R };

const objectMap: ObjectMap = (obj, fun) =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(fun));

const result = objectMap({ a: 2, b: 4 }, ([key, val]) => [key, val * 2]); 
console.log(result); // {a: 4, b: 8}
```

([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AWQIZigXigHgDUAaKAJQD4AKAKCigHtEAuKAbygG0BnV74AE4BLAHYBzALqtCUAL5QAPlACCAgRhAAZIQGsIRCsTpQAZgFcRrKhgFjWPQaLGlCEgJS4KXAAoCGkAVAAaQgQUjIJGg8cLw4ePkdxKXI5AG4aGmQGEX5GRBR0LFZ4JFRMbDwqJgRScxFoimMSgoA6Ez8AWwBREUcIbipm1BaIXuF+qsQ3Fo6sKjq3N3TM7NyBfrMAG2BcPNLCsCoODFYAJlI4VgAWOVIqTj0wqAA3DE33Ty5H0lfNqAAqKCndypKArHIMTYQFqbBhiKjrbhbYBLKAAejR7BOUCuF1YAA5ZDQgA))